# Must manually refresh Windows Explorer after creating new files/folders in document library

Tags: webdav, explorer, windows

We have just setup Sharepoint 2010 internally for testing and development.

I created a simple document library, and mapped it up in Windows Explorer.

It works OK - it's reasonably fast (at least after I disabled 'automatically detect settings' in Internet Explorer...) - however, when I create a new folder or a new textfile nothing happens until I hit f5 - then my new folder or file is instantly showing. I can hit F5 0.1 seconds after I created the folder and it shows instantly. But it does not show until I refresh.

I have tried on several machines. Any tips or suggestions?

Comment: It's not designed to reflect your changes immediately. The explorer view works like a network drive (webdav). I think webdav doesn't support pushing back changes to a client when they happen. And if it does; they didn't implement it. So I'm afraid your stuck F5-ing.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 is deprecated and doesn't get any security patches.
If you are using SharePoint 2010 Foundation, try installing SharePoint 2013 Foundation instead to get at least two more years of security patches.